# Directives, Services & ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building a complex, variable layout with infinite scroll UI in AngularJS.

Think something like Flipboard with a load of repeating data items, each item containing the same thing (title, description, image etc).  Each item is pre-loaded into JSON, sorted and then organised into a series of pages, selected from a series of variable layouts.  Each page has a variable number columns and each column a variable number of rows.

In order to achieve this, I'm using multiple Directives for each page layout, compiled at run time.  Inside each layout Directive, I'm then building a variable number of columns, each of which contains an ng-repeat for the variable number of rows.  Each row can be a different Directive, depending on how it needs to be styled.  Again, all of this is happening at runtime.

I'm 99% of the way there.

The Directives are being compiled correctly and calling up the correct column Directives, which in turn are compiling the correct number of rows.  Once we get to the row/item level, I'm using a Service which brings back the correct Directive for each item.  The reason I choose the Service approach is that I want the items to be reused inside other modules.

The problem I'm having, is that once the page layout is compiled, it sets up the columns and then the rows but does not execute the ng-repeat.  I need to get the ng-repeat to loop and also call the specific Directives I use for each item.

I think is a problem to do with $compile and what Angular knows about the DOM.  Maybe I need to do a $compile or $apply at some stage to get the ng-repeat to kick in and bind the final Directives to the data items.

**

Side note: if I don't use a Service, but simply use define each layout Directive with a templateUri it works perfectly!

I can go with this approach, but ideally, I'd like to get away from downloading a bunch of templates at runtime.  Also, by passing parameters into a Service, I can design more layouts, much quicker and easier than having to build individual template files.

I've set up a JS fiddle with quick example of how I'm approaching all of this:

http://jsfiddle.net/joecarney/vE3Ls/6/

Some SO required code just to post this comment:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appPageController">
    <div>
        <div my-page></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you build with grunt, you can use `ngtemplates` to inline the templates in the directives.  Then you won't download extra templates at runtime.

Comment: not the point. i want to create my own templates in code, using JSON. that way i don't need to inline them.  i can configure as many as i need with variables and may even create new random ones at runtime, based on the unknown data items i have coming through...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `scope: {}` in a directive it creates a new scope so your directives will not have access to controller scope unless you allow it, which you started out doing but appears you then copied and pasted the same thing for all :)

The directive compiling items in ng-repeat had no access to items. I removed scope from directives and used the attrs value to access the attributes

http://jsfiddle.net/vE3Ls/7/